# How do you access the Product Short Description in a WooCommerce email template?

Tags: templates, email, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to output the Product Short Description beneath the product name inside the order items table inside WooCommerce emails. I think I know where to place code inside the email template file, but I don't know how to access the description of an item. I don't see any mechanism to retrieve it. What do I need to do to echo out the field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally tried using `var_dump()` on `$item` and `$_product`, which are both used in the `email-order-items.php` template. `$_product` revealed a `post` object, which itself has a `post_excerpt` property, which looks like it holds the contents of the "Product Short Description" from the WooCommerce product form.

So, to add the description beneath the item name, I added this to my code:

`echo '<br/>' . $_product->post->post_excerpt;`

Voilà! The short description appears in the email!

Hope this helps someone else!  Took me a couple hours of frustration to get it.

Comment: If you are inside the loop, you can use ```<?php the_excerpt(); ?>```

Comment: $post->post_excerpt will also work fine in the loop, moreover it will also get the full text (without shorten the description) .