# How can I remove the product short description from the WooCommerce Mails?

Tags: email, wp-mail, description

I do have a rather large short description because it does fit perfectly with my theme, but unfortunately those information are added to the emails that are send to customers and mess with their format. 
I know I could just add the description to the regular field, but it doesn't look as nice on the product page.
Is there a way to remove these short descriptions from those mails?

Cheers

Comment: This link gives answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184952/how-do-you-access-the-product-short-description-in-a-woocommerce-email-template

Comment: I've seen that one, but there it is about adding the short description, not removing it. I'm also too much of a rookie to use that information and turn it around I fear.